# Command to render all images in a dir into one browser window, from term?

Tags: webserver, images, browser

Command to render all images in a dir into one browser window, from term?

What's a good command from the terminal (I'm running OSX 10.10.2) to render all images in a directory into one browser window?

Looking for something like this:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080
```

But instead of getting back a naked list of files ...

... I would like to see **all of the images in the dir rendered in a single browser window**, just flowed naturally, at natural dimensions; just scroll down for how many images there are to see them all in their natural rendered state.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!